# Unable to load requested field type file: ft.rel.php Tried all fixes listed

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades, ee

Getting this message whenever I try to do anything with field-types.

This was a 2.6.1 installation, I’ve tried updating to 2.10.1, but I get exactly the same error message.

I’ve tried all the common solutions I can think of, here is the exp_fieldtypes table in my DB:

```
1 select 1.0 YTowOnt9 n
2 text 1.0 YTowOnt9 n
3 textarea 1.0 YTowOnt9 n
4 date 1.0 YTowOnt9 n
5 file 1.0 YTowOnt9 n
6 multi_select 1.0 YTowOnt9 n
7 checkboxes 1.0 YTowOnt9 n
8 radio 1.0 YTowOnt9 n
```

I can’t even get into addons - > Field types as it just throws this error.

There is nothing using a relationship field anywhere as far as I can see. I’ve searched the entire codebase for any reference to ft.rel.php and ft.rel and I can’t find any references to it anywhere.

I assume it must be been referenced the DB somewhere but I can’t see it anywhere unless it is encrypted data somewhere.

Basically I can’t edit or change anything to do the with channel fields or this error comes up when I even try and view them.

Please help! I’m at my wits end trying to find a solution here!

Comment: Solved, our sys admin did a s-trace on the php process and found it was looking for the file in 3 weird folders......

     system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/rel/ft.rel.php
     system/expressionengine/third_party/12/ft.rel.php
     system/expressionengine/modules/rel/ft.rel.php

Copying the ft.rel.php file to the first one fixed it. 
No idea why it was looking there for it, we've never had anything at all living there.....

No in fieldtypes I can see the two relationship(s) fieldtypes there, both uninstalled...... if they are uninstalled why is it looking for the files! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved, our sys admin did a s-trace on the php process and found it was looking for the file in 3 weird folders......

```
system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/rel/ft.rel.php
system/expressionengine/third_party/12/ft.rel.php
system/expressionengine/modules/rel/ft.rel.php
```

Copying the ft.rel.php file to the first one fixed it. No idea why it was looking there for it, we've never had anything at all living there..... No in fieldtypes I can see the two relationship(s) fieldtypes there, both uninstalled...... if they are uninstalled why is it looking for the files! :